# Virtual directory and Tridion

Tags: 2011, dd4t

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1 and have a DD4T website hosted under a single site in IIS as a subdirectory to cut cost. Due to the subdirectory we have to specify Publication URL '/xyz' in the Publication property.

Once we publish from tridion the URL for the page is having 'xyz' - the subdirectory twice The page is inaccessible on the single 'xyz'. I have checked the db and there the URL is correct with one 'xyz' i.e. '/xyz/page_name'. I believe the other 'xyz' is coming via the website setup in IIS(//server_name/subdirectory/).

Please let me know how can we have the website URL with single 'xyz' in the same setup of virtual directory.

I would also like to highlight that another non-DD4T website with a similar setup in IIS is having a single subdirectory in it's URL where the URL in the db is showing with one subdirectory like the DD4T website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC disregards the ApplicationPath in the URL (so in your case '/xyz'). This means that the pages should end up in the broker database without this string. If your page is stored with the url '/xyz/pagename.extension', this is incorrect!

To correct this, simply set the value of the *Publication URL* property to an empty string. The *Publication Path* property is ignored altogether, since that is only used when a page is stored on the file system (which shouldn't be the case with a DD4T implementation).

Comment: Thanks!! But if I remove the Publication URL, then none of the component links are getting resolved. The URL is coming as //server_name/page_name/ after removing instead of //server_name/subdirectory/page_name.

Comment: Could you post that as a separate question please? I have a solution for this as well, but I don't want to mix it in with my other answer.